# Numpy einsum compute outer product along axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-einsum

I have two numpy arrays that contain compatible matrices and want to compute the element wise outer product of using [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). The shapes of the arrays would be:

```
A1 = (i,j,k)
A2 = (i,k,j)
```

Therefore the arrays contain `i` matrices of shape `(k,j)` and `(j,k)` respectively.

So given `A1` would contain the matrices `A,B,C` and `A2` would contain matrices `D,E,F`, the result would be:

```
A3 = (A(x)D,B(x)E,C(x)F)
```

With `(x)` being the outer product operator.

This would yield to my understanding based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973559/outer-product-of-two-matrices) an array `A3` of the following shape:

```
A3 = (i,j*k,j*k)
```

So far I have tried:

```
np.einsum("ijk, ilm -> ijklm", A1, A2)
```

But the resulting shapes do not fit correctly.

As a sanity check I am testing for this:

```
A = np.asarray(([1,2],[3,4]))
B = np.asarray(([5,6],[7,8]))

AB_outer = np.outer(A,B)

A_vec = np.asarray((A,A))
B_vec = np.asarray((B,B))

# this line is not correct
AB_vec = np.einsum("ijk, ilm -> ijklm", A_vec,B_vec)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(AB_outer, AB_vec[0])
```

This currently throws an assertion error as my einsum notation is not correct. I am also open to any suggestions that can solve this and are faster or equally fast as nymphs einsum.

Comment: What do you mean by an outer product of matrices? An outer product is typically an operation on vectors.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am referring to the definition as described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973559/outer-product-of-two-matrices.

Comment: @Divakar I just finished testing; works out great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can extend dims and let [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) do the job for us -

```
(A1[:,:,None,:,None]*A2[:,None,:,None,:]).swapaxes(2,3)
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: A1 = np.random.rand(3,4,4)
    ...: A2 = np.random.rand(3,4,4)

In [47]: out = (A1[:,:,None,:,None]*A2[:,None,:,None,:]).swapaxes(2,3)

In [48]: np.allclose(np.multiply.outer(A1[0],A2[0]), out[0])
Out[48]: True

In [49]: np.allclose(np.multiply.outer(A1[1],A2[1]), out[1])
Out[49]: True

In [50]: np.allclose(np.multiply.outer(A1[2],A2[2]), out[2])
Out[50]: True
```

The equivalent with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) would be -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijklm',A1,A2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the result running:

```
result = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', A1, A2)
```

I checked the above code on the following test data:

```
A = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(3, -1)
B = np.arange(2, 14).reshape(3, -1)
C = np.arange(3, 15).reshape(3, -1)
D = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(4, -1)
E = np.arange(2, 14).reshape(4, -1)
F = np.arange(3, 15).reshape(4, -1)
A1 = np.array([A, B, C])
A2 = np.array([D, E, F])
```

The result is:

```
array([[[ 70,  80,  90],
        [158, 184, 210],
        [246, 288, 330]],

       [[106, 120, 134],
        [210, 240, 270],
        [314, 360, 406]],

       [[150, 168, 186],
        [270, 304, 338],
        [390, 440, 490]]])
```

Now compute 3 "partial results":

```
res_1 = A @ D
res_2 = B @ E
res_3 = C @ F
```

and check that they are just the same as consecutive sections of the result.