# Python standardized function for axis-specific outer product

Tags: python, numpy, outer-product

I have two matrices X and V with respective shape (K, M) and (K,L)
The first dimension represents the batch_size (each row is a singular element from the batch).
I wish to do the outer product only on dimensions 1 on both of these matrices such that the output has the shape (K, M, L).

I have of course tried to use the NumPy [np.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function but it flattens the arrays and the result is of final shape (K * M, K * L)

Is there a function in one of Python's standard libraries that can do the operation I want to do ?

An example of what I want, but it is not efficient :

```py
W = np.zeros(K,M,L)
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    W[i,:,:] = np.outer(X[i,:], V[i,:])
```

Edit: Found an answer already on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific problem, adding an extra dimension and letting Python do the broadcasting was sufficient.

My working code:

```py
W = X[:,:,None]*V[:,None,:]
```

Thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485289/20984671) for helping me out.